# How to check equality of spark columns after renaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write some tests for a Java Spark-Sql application.  One operation I need to test renames a column, and I ran into some difficulty comparing the actual value of the renamed column with my expected value.  After some experimentation, I was able to write the following two tests to demonstrate the problem:

First, as a sanity check, I tried this (df is a spark sql `DataFrame`, generated by reading some sample data from a json file I'm testing against):

```
  @Test
  public void testColumnEquality() throws Exception {
    Column val1 = df.col("col2");
    Column val2 = df.col("col2");
    Assert.assertEquals(val1, val2);
  }
```

Which passes, as one would expect.  Then I tried this:

```
  @Test
  public void testReanmeColumnEquality() throws Exception {
    Column val1 = df.col("col2").as("col2");
    Column val2 = df.col("col2").as("col2");
    Assert.assertEquals(val1, val2);
  }
```

which fails with the error `java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<col2 AS col2#4L> but was:<col2 AS col2#5L>`

Digging around in the scala code (full disclosure - I know very little scala) it looks like this has to do with the `NamedExpression` unique id.

Is there any way to sensibly check that these two columns represent the same operations with the same alias?

(I'm working in spark 1.6, and would ideally like a solution for that version line, but if this is fixed in 2.0 that would also be good information.)

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote [a blog post](http://www.agardner.me/spark/scala/java/testing/dataframe/2016/09/30/spark-column-comparison.html) about how to resolve this:

The trick is: check whether the `Expression` has the `Alias` trait:

```
`column.expr() instanceof Alias`
```

If it does, unpack the child expression and the name using the Extractor pattern:

```
alias = (Alias) column.expr()
Option<Tuple2<Expression, String>> aliasTuple = Alias$.MODULE$.unapply(alias);
```

Comment: Can you do it in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and it looks like the information about the child of a `Column` with an alias is lost in the process of instantiating the new Column. Maybe there is a state to query somewhere, but I didn't find it.

So it's not an answer, but hopefully it is useful or of interest to somebody.

**more info**

The definition of the `as` method on a `Column` object refers to the `name` function (see [Column.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.scala)), which just call the `Alias` case class defined [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/namedExpressions.scala). The `Alias` (with its `child`), is not exposed. It is directly given to the `Column` class `withExpr` function which instantiate a new column based on the `Alias` named expression.

So you either compare directly the result of `toString` on the columns (loosing the information on where the column comes from, i.e. which dataframe), or you actually parse the string *printed* by the `explain(true)` method...but it doesn't seem sensible to me...